# How to call an 2D - Array which was initiated in another class?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, boolean, method-call

I made a minimal reduced example of my problem: the `Maze` class creates a 2D boolean array with the method `generateMaze()` (the content of `mazeArray` is irrelevant in this example). The main thread from `Walker` calls that method and thereby creates this `mazeArray` from the `Maze` class.

I do not understand how I can call this array in `Walker.walk`? I'm afraid I have a knowledge gap.

Every hint is appreciated, thank you very much.

```
public final class Maze {

public static boolean[][] generateMaze(int width, int height) {

    boolean[][] mazeArray = new boolean[width][height];

    for( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
        mazeArray[x][0] = true;
    }
    for( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        mazeArray[0][y] = true;
    }
    return mazeArray;
}

}

public class Walker {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Maze mazeObj  = new Maze();
    boolean[][] maze = Maze.generateMaze(2,2);
}

public void walk(Maze maze) {
   // Traverse Array
}

}
```

Comment: You lack basics of OOP, I suggest you step back and take a look at some tutorial first. Personally, I can recommend this free course: https://java-programming.mooc.fi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

There are several *basic OOP* mistakes here.

First of all, why do you even create an instance of the `Maze` class when your `generateMaze` class is `static` and returns the maze as instance of `boolean[][]` instead of `Maze`. You probably intended to have the array as a field of the class instead and not access the array directly but via a maze instance.

Next, the `walk` method is non-static and part of `Walker` instances. So you would need to create an instance of that class and call the method on that instance.

---

### Maze generation

You probably intended to do this instead:

```java
public final class Maze {
  // Arrays as field of maze instances
  private boolean[][] mazeArray;

  // return maze instance instead of array
  public static Maze generateMaze(int width, int height) {
    // create maze instance
    Maze maze = new Maze();
    // manipulate array of that maze instance
    maze.mazeArray = new boolean[width][height];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        maze.mazeArray[x][0] = true;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        maze.mazeArray[0][y] = true;
    }

    // return the maze, not its array
    return maze;
  }
}
```

with a call like

```java
Maze maze = Maze.generateMaze(2, 2);
```

##### Constructor

Or even better, use a constructor:

```java
public final class Maze {
  private final boolean[][] mazeArray;

  public Maze(int width, int height) {
    mazeArray = new boolean[width][height];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        mazeArray[x][0] = true;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        mazeArray[0][y] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

And call it like this in your `main`:

```java
Maze maze = new Maze(2, 2);
```

##### Factory

You can still couple that with a factory method, if you really want. But the creation logic should be in a (possibly `private`) constructor nonetheless:

```java
public final class Maze {
  private final boolean[][] mazeArray;

  private Maze(int width, int height) {
    mazeArray = new boolean[width][height];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        mazeArray[x][0] = true;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        mazeArray[0][y] = true;
    }
  }

  public static Maze generate(int width, int height) {
    return new Maze(width, height);
  }
}
```

calling it like:

```java
Maze maze = Maze.generate(2, 2);
```

---

### Walker

Now, you need an instance of the `Walker` class and call the method on that, giving it the maze you just generated:

```java
Maze maze = new Maze(2, 2);
Walker walker = new Walker();

walker.walk(maze);
```

Comment: Very helpfull, thank you very much. This is a design-pattern technique isn´t it?

Comment: Ur welcome. Im not sure if it has a dedicated name. To me, this is just some basics about OOP. Constructors, static, non-static, methods and well, factory methods.